# Import common functions in all activities android

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I am working on an android app that has a menu at the top (like we have in websites; home, aboutus etc). This menu is repeated in all the activities so I have to repeat the code for these in all activities. Is there a way that I can write the code once in some class and reuse it in all other activities using inheritance or something? (Just lice there is include function in php). Hope my question is straight forward. Here is the code for the menu that I have to repeat everywhere.

```
// menu items
menu_home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});
menu_help.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});
menu_media.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MediaActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});
menu_index.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, IndexActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});
```

[image]

Comment: i'd recommend to use fragments instead, this way you can put the layout and functionality of your menu into a single fragment and inflate it in several activities (if necessary, you might also just use one activity and just swap fragments) google for "android master detail"

Answer (score 2):

> I have to repeat the code for these in all activities.

Java does not support multiple inheritances.

Don’t use inheritance just to get code reuse. If there is no **is a** relationship then use composition for code reuse. Overuse of implementation inheritance (aka `extends`) can break all the sub-classes, if the superclass is modified.

[image]

In you case I would use **composition**. Just create new class that implements above mentioned Listener logic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can..for this take one MainActivty and write your menu code in that..after then all your activitys extend that MainActivity like below..

```
class  MainActivty extend Activity{
}

class FirstActivity extend MainActivity{
}


class SecondActivity extend MainActivity{
}
```

Then menu will appear in your all activitys..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a layout and include it like this:

```
<include
android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
layout="@layout/login_header"
/>
```

It has its own class file where common functionality can be kept.

Comment: And where do I put this..in the xml right? this seems be simpler than other comments above. Hope this helps me.

Comment: in all of your layout where u want to show your menu. This implementation works same as your understanding of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

it's very easy you just create a class

```
class  MenuActivty extend Activity{
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.mymenu_home).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
    });
    
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.mymenu_help).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
    });

//... same thing for the others
    }
}
```

be careful to rename the menu "mymenu" in all the XML

and all the classes where you want to use the menu should be extended MenuActivty

and in the XML use

```
<include layout="@layout/menulayout "
    android:id="@+id/mymenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and create an XML file named menulayout where you put the layout of your menu.

Comment: What is to be done in MainActivity where I want to use this onclick of menu?

Comment: Simply extending the class like > public class MainActivity extends MenuActivity did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a generic layout for menu and include it wherever you want to use it.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    layout="@layout/login_header"
    />
```

2. Create a class CentralizedHeader. Create on constructor with one parameter of activity type.
3. Create a function here and initialize all views and perform all related functionality here.

```
public class CentralizedHeader {

  private Button btnHome, btnContribute;
  private Activity activity;

  public CentralizedHeader(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  public void headerActions() {

    btnHome = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_home);
    btnContribute = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_contribute);

    btnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MorePackagesActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
      }
    });

    btnContribute.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ContributeActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

4. Create an object of this class in other activity and call its function. ie

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private CentralizedHeader headerCentralized;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home_tab);
        headerCentralized = new CentralizedHeader(this);
        headerCentralized.headerActions();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to reuse function in java class:

1. make a Singleton class so that that instance is anywhere you can get
2. mention all your code in this class
3. use all method from this class

and if you use that layout also then just make one xml and include it in all layout where you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one **Activity** that have all the menus and create **Fragments** for activity. Replace fragment on clicking to the menu. This is the good way to achieve your functionality as you want.